# Will threading make my function faster in this case?

Tags: python, python-multithreading, pyautogui

I am making a bot that uses pyautogui and OCR. It's for a game that it's divided by phases and each phase is represented by an icon, I'm using pyautogui to detect that icon on the screen and my code is more or less this

```
def handle_match(player, region):

day_icon = locateOnScreen(template_paths.DAY_ICON, confidence=0.7, region=region)

while day_icon is not None: 
    day_icon = locateOnScreen(template_paths.DAY_ICON, confidence=0.7, region=region) 

    # DO STUFF HERE, STUFF INCLUDES OCR FUNCTIONS AND OTHERS
```

I measured each iteration and they take between 1.4 and 2.2 seconds. I was talking to a friend and he suggested using a separate thread for phase detection (the detection of the icon) and do the OCR stuff and others in the main thread but I'm not sure if threading will make this faster, since as far as I know image recognition functions are CPU bound (correct me if I'm wrong please)
I measured the time that locateOnScreen takes and it's between 0.1 and 0.2 seconds. Personally, I don't think threading will make this any faster but I would like to hear your opinions

Note: `locateOnScreen` is a pyautogui function, not a custom one

Comment: No. Multithreading will not help if the task is CPU bound, which it sounds like this is.  Multiprocessing could improve your performance though.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running on a low CPU bound, `multi-threading` will slow down your performance. i would suggest `multi-processing`.